# iis7 wcf: on local computer I get 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: wcf, service, iis-7

I am new to web services and I have following problem. I have a WCF service that is running in Windows Authentication mode on IIS 7.5 and Windows 2008 R2.
It works good when I call it directly from the IIS machine.
But when I try to call service from local computer then I get following error: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

The service was working on local computers for few days and suddenly it stopped (I am not sure but it is possible that some configuration was changed).

I call service directly from IExplorer: `http://serveriis/ssopension/service.svc`

web.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>O8jBoF9YUW3sZtSN+L/Xxhzss=</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>C+EeTszivHho8Ujk2oIQ==</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>


<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SSO_Pension.ServiceBehavior" name="SSO_Pension.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="SSO_Pension.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SSO_Pension.ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>


    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Service.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the logged in your of the local computer has access to the WCF service?

Comment: When I am logged to local computer then I have access to shares on the IIS server and I can read and write to share with WCF services.

Comment: Is it the same user you are running your client application that tries to access the WCF service. Also make sure that Windows Authentication is enabled on IIS

Comment: It is the same user. And I just type service's address in the internet explorer and then access is denied.
Windows Authentication is enabled on IIS in service configuration.

Also there is other IIS application just with a html file and with windows authentication enabled and I can run it from my local computer.

Maybe something is wrong with web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/c9239a89-fbee-4adc-b72f-7a6a9648331f/

> To whoever this may help, this saved my life...
>
> IIS 7 was difficult for figuring out why i was getting the 401 -
>   Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials... until i
>   did this...
>
> 1.) Open iis and select the website that is causing the 401
>
> 2.) Open the "Authentication" property under the "IIS" header
>
> 3.) Click the "Windows Authentication" item and click "Providers"
>
> 4.) For me the issue was that Negotiate was above NTLM. I assume that there was some kind of handshake going on behind the scenes, but i was
>   never really authenticated. I moved the NTLM to the top most spot, and
>   BAM that fixed it.

Comment: I was skeptical that this would work, but it worked for the environment that I was in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man!

I've been searching everywhere for this, including these two articles:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/10/wcf-calling-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis-on-the-same-machine-as-client-throws-an-authentication-error.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;926642

This solved my problem.